# Items created by Repeater have incorrect geometry

Tags: qt, layout, qml, qtquick2

I want to show four checkable buttons in a row:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    id: main
    visible: true
    width: 600; height: 350

    ColumnLayout {
        id: mainColumn

        anchors.fill: parent // takes all available width
        RowLayout {
            Repeater {
                id: rep
                model: ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
                Component.onCompleted: console.log(count)
                Button {
                    text: modelData
                    checkable: true
                    Layout.preferredWidth: mainColumn.width / rep.count // (!)
                }
            }
        }
        // more elements
    }
}
```

Then the fourth button is cut off (as though additional spacing was introduced or the buttons were too wide).

If I use `Row` instead of `RowLayout` and `width` instead of `Layout.preferredWidth`, the items are displayed correctly.

Why aren't they with `RowLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Row` and `RowLayout` have the `spacing` property. However, if you read the documentation for `Row` [`spacing`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-row.html#spacing-prop) you can see that

> The spacing is the amount in pixels left empty between adjacent items. The **default spacing is 0**.

whereas the `RowLayout` [`spacing`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html#spacing-prop) reads

> This property holds the spacing between each cell. The **default value is 5**.

So, basically, adds `spacing: 0` to your `RowLayout`.